# Why is this appearing to select wrong number of lines?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-mode

First, I typed `2V` to select two lines, and `y` to yank them. Then I typed `3V`, and instead of selecting 3 lines, Vim selects 6 lines. Next I typed `4V` and Vim selected 8 lines. It seems that 3 or 4 in the later selections are multiplied by  the 2 in the first selection for yanking.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it seem counter intuitive, this behaviour seems to be the expected one. From `:help V`:

```
[count]V            Start Visual mode linewise.                                                                                                                                                                
                    With [count] select the same number of lines as used                                                                                                                                       
                    for the last Visual operation, but at the current                                                                                                                                          
                    cursor position, multiplied by [count].  When there                                                                                                                                        
                    was no previous Visual operation [count] lines are                                                                                                                                         
                    selected.
```

Answer (score 2):

To be precise, `[count]V` select `[count] * (lines of last visual operation)` lines if and only if last visual operation is linewise (V).

In fact if last visual operation exists, `[count]v`, `[count]V` and `[count]<c-v>` are the same, they select `[count] * (visual area of last visual operation)` in the same wise mode with last visual operation.

If last visual operation doesn't exist, `[count]v` select `[count]`characters to right, `[count]V` select `[count]` lines down, `[count]<c-v>` select the same area with `[count]v` but in block wise.

Comment: Thanks. A question, what if I select and yank 3 lines, and then I want to select 4 lines, when 4 can't be [count] * 3?

Comment: `1vj` or `V3j`. If you just want to yank 4 lines, use `4yy`.